# Selenium Python Chrome: Extremely slow. Are cookies the problem?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I read that Selenium Chrome can run faster if you use implicit waits, headless, ID and CSS selectors etc. Before implementing those changes, I want to know whether cookies or caching could be slowing me down.

Does Selenium store cookies and cache like a normal browser or does it reload all assets everytime it navigates to a new page on a website?

If yes, then this would slow down the process of scraping websites with millions of identical profile pages, where the scripts and images are similar for each profile.

Is yes, is there a way to avoid this problem? Interested in using cookies and cache during a session and then destroying after the browser is closed.

Edit, more details:

```
sel_options = {'proxy': {'https': pString}}
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : dFolder}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
blocker = os.path.join( os.getcwd(), "extension_iijehicfndmapfeoplkdpinnaicikehn")
options.add_argument(f"--load-extension={blocker}")
wS = "--window-size="+s1+","+s2
options.add_argument(wS)
if headless == "yes": options.add_argument("--headless");
driver = uc.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=sel_options, options=options, use_subprocess=True, version_main=109)
stealth(driver, languages=["en-US", "en"], vendor="Google Inc.", platform="Win32",  webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.", renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine", fix_hairline=True)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": agent})
navigate("https://linkedin.com")
```

I don't think my proxy or extension is the culprit, because I have a similar automation app running with no speed issue.

Comment: This is a very broad question. You should provide more information about the page you're actually loading, and an example of the code you're running. Currently the answer has to be "yes, theoretically your specific cookies could be causing a slowdown, but it's far more likely many other factors are causing more of a perfomance hit".

Comment: No problem. More details added.

Comment: **uc** + **seleniumwire** + **stealth**, are you sure what you are asking for?

Comment: Maybe that is overkill, I just don't want to be detected as selenium. Do you think the problem might be that I have not specified a directory for cache and cookies to be stored?

Comment: if speed is the goal you should try something light-weight like HTMLUnit.   Cookies and caching would be the same as usual, methinks.  It's just that, by default, you'll have a new and temporary profile.  You can set your webdriver options to use an existing profile if you like.

Comment: Remember that Selenium is literally running Chrome.  It's not simulating Chrome, it is controlling a Chrome instance.  I'm struck by "millions of identical profile pages".  If an infinitely fast human typist tried to pull millions of pages, it would take a very long time, if for no other reason than network delays.  Selenium cannot do any better.

Comment: Would you provide more of your code?  I'm interesting in the section, which deals with how you are navigating to the profile pages that you're scraping.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Selenium WebDriver may not enable caching or store cookies like a normal browser and yes i do think that is always interesting to use session caching instead of re-downloading the same files after each scraping cron job run.

### Cache (Selenium/Chrome) with a static browser profile:

You can create a Chrome profile with caching enabled and then use that profile with Selenium. This way, the browser will utilize the same profile directory to store all your files during all your scraping runs and you may not lose files in between runs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/path/to/profile/folder")
options.add_argument("--disk-cache-dir=/path/to/cache/folder")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Replace `/path/to/profile/folder` with the desired folder where you want to store the profile data, and `/path/to/cache/folder` with the folder where you want to store the cache. This way, the browser will utilize the cache during subsequent page loads within the same session.

It is also good to know that the python selenium library provides methods to manage cookies. You can use `driver.manage().getCookies()` to retrieve cookies and `driver.manage().addCookie(cookie)` to add a cookie to the current session.

Comment: the browser will save/load cookies just as it normally would... it's just that the browser, when launched by a webdriver, will by default use a temporary profile (unless you set it in options as above) and delete it after the browser closes.  Within that session everything is the same, though.  (cookies will persist after page loads for instance...)

Comment: Interesting. So the guy above is wrong? Navigating from page A to page B (without closing the browser) will preserve cookies and cache (in a temporary folder) in a similar way to a regular browser. So my speed issue is not related to cookies + cache?

Comment: I am guessing that you are not taking into consideration that scraping is usually a cron that will launch every "X" times a day. As pcalkins pointed out in his comment using a temporary profile all data would (should by default) be deleted after the browser close (means after each execution of that cron scraping script). So unless you set up a static profile (as above) I don't think that you can avoid this data deletion after each run. So basically this could help avoid recreating a new session and re-downloading files after each cron execution.

Comment: @NedHulton It is highly unlikely that your scraping speed is related to cookies and caching.  Scraping *millions of profiles* will take lots of time to scrape using your current code design.  Plus there is potential that you are getting throttled (rate-limited) by LinkedIn for scraping too many pages during a defined period of time.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `chromedriver` being used by `Selenium` interacts with the cookies provided by the website [linkedIn.com](https://www.linkedin.com/) which you are scraping.  These cookies will only be maintained by the  `chromedriver` until you close the driver session.  When you launch a new instance of `chromedriver` the old cookies do not exist.  [LinkedIn.com](https://www.linkedin.com/) will provide a new batch of cookies to use in this with new `chromedriver` session.

In my opinion the cookies and caching from an active session aren’t causing your performance issues when scraping [linkedIn.com](https://www.linkedin.com/).

You stated in your question that you were `scraping millions of identical profile pages` on [linkedIn.com](https://www.linkedin.com/). Scraping this many profiles is very time consuming even for an automated `Selenium` session. The mostly likely culprit of your performance issue is `rate-limiting` being imposed by [linkedIn.com](https://www.linkedin.com/).

I would assume that you are receiving `HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code` when your scraping activities become slow. You would need to do some debugging to determine this.

Here is some code that you can modified to get the HTTP status code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
capabilities['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get(f'https://www.linkedin.com')

perfLog = driver.get_log('performance')
for logIndex in range(0, len(perfLog)):  # Parse the Chrome Performance logs
    logMessage = json.loads(perfLog[logIndex]["message"])["message"]
    if logMessage["method"] == "Network.responseReceived":  # Filter out HTTP responses
        print(logMessage["params"]["response"])
```

I noted that when I was checking the status code for my connection that [linkedIn.com](https://www.linkedin.com/) also using [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/) for protection. This is going to create a major issue when `scraping millions of identical profile pages` on [linkedIn.com](https://www.linkedin.com/). You will likely get blocked or your proxy addresses will get blacklisted.

Your current code will require redesigning to handle `rate-limiting`, `status codes of 429` and any `cloudflare` hurdles.